# Flex is it possible to access/play a video located in a shared folder?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

If i am going to use a video URL placed in a shared folder (in another machine), the video couldn't be played

load("\192.168.0.10\SampleVideo\15.mp4");

but it worked fine if i put this video in my project assets

load("assets/SampleVideo/15.mp4");

How can i load/play a video using UNC path?

The same problem in using an image source.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Flex does not support all the existing protocols...

In fact, only a few are supported out of the box : HTTP, HTTPS and the local files.

Here is the doc of the URLRequest and the list of supported protocols:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html
- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8f6c0-7ffe.html

If you want to use others protocols, you must use 3rd party libraries (for FTP for instance), but ASAIK, nothing exists for UNC.

M.